# POST JSON to ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, json, .net, post

I am coding both a client and an API in C# .Net4.8. I am POSTing data from the client and I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` on the endpoint method. I want to read the POSTed data within the `ActionFilterAttribute` method. I found I was able to POST form data using `FormUrlEncodedContent` and it is received, but when I try POSTing JSON data using `stringContent` it is not received.

**How can I change either my client side code or API code to POST JSON correctly?**

POSTing form data like so works:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
FormUrlEncodedContent formString = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, formString).Result; // run synchronously
```

And then on the API side, `dataFromClient` gets populated:

```
public class myFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Feature { get; set; }
    public myFilter(string feature)
    {
        this.Feature = feature;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string dataFromClient = (HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["dataFromClient"] == null) ? "" : HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["dataFromClient"];
        // do other stuff with dataFromClient here
    }
}
```

POSTing JSON data like so does not work:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent).Result; // run synchronously
```

With this method, `dataFromClient` in the API is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're posting `application/json`,you should read request body. I think, here's what you want;

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
    var initialBody = request.Body;
    
    try
    {
        request.EnableRewind();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            string dataFromClient = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // do other stuff with dataFromClient here

            return dataFromClient;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        request.Body = initialBody; 
    }

    filterContext.Request.Body.Position = 0

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I did see this as a solution in other SO questions and i tried it, but the line `var initialBody = request.Body;` does not compile - probably because i'm using .net4.8? It gives me the error "'HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'Body'"